# How can I use generic class structure in that situation

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use the code like below, I get a subtype of type error. If **final bool Function(T)? isExpandable;** instead of **final bool Function(LocationModel)? isExpandable;** If I define it as , there is no problem. How should I do it generically?

```
        class ModalListWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
          final bool Function(T)? isExpandable;
          final List<T> dynamicList;
          
        const ModalListWidget({
            Key? key,
            required this.dynamicList,
            this.isExpandable,
          }
    
    ) : super(key: key);
 @override
  _ModalListWidgetState createState() => _ModalListWidgetState();
}

class _ModalListWidgetState extends State<ModalListWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: widget.dynamicList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context2, index) {
              return ModalRowWidget(
                onExpanded: () => widget.onTap?.call(widget.dynamicList[index].id),              
                },
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

**I call it like this on another page.
**

```
ModalListWidget<LocationModel>(
                isExpandable: (location) => location.childLocationsCount > 0,)
```

**this is the error**
[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: Where do you use your `isExpandable` function in your `ModalListWidget` class?

Comment: onExpanded: () => widget.onTap?.call(widget.dynamicList[index].id),  is wrong. I am sory for that.

it would be like this : 
onExpanded:  widget.isExpandable ?.call(widget.dynamicList[index]) ?? false,